# RenderListWheelViewport object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: flutter, dart, delegates, flutter-layout, infinite

I am using `ListWheelScrollView` Widget to give a wheeling effect to my list item but getting the error as mentioned. I just want to show Stacked Items with some image and texts in individual list item and give a 3D Wheeling effect to them.

Below is my code ->

```
class ExploreWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ExploreState();
}

class _ExploreState extends State<ExploreWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: null,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _header(),
          _exploreList()
        ],
      )
    );

  }

  Widget _header(){
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      width: 800,
    );

  }

  Widget _exploreList(){
    return ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
      itemExtent: 75,
      childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
        builder:(context,index){
          return Container(
            height: 500,
            width: 800,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image(image: AssetImage(
                  _products[index].image
                )),
                Text(_products[index].name,style: Style.sectionTitleWhite,),
                Text('70% off',style: Style.cardListTitleWhite,),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was occuring due to the way `_exploreList()` widget is implemented. This widget is wrapped inside `Column` which doesn't scroll in itself. Moreover, you are returning a `ScrollView` that has an infinite size. Hence it was throwing the said error. To resolve this issue, wrap `_exploreList()` widget inside `Flexible` which takes only minimum available space to render and scroll. Working sample code below:

```
body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _header(),
            Flexible(
              child: _exploreList()
            )
          ],
        )
```

Now you should be able to use `WheelScrollView` properly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @darshan for your answer :)